# ASP.NET Core - How to know deserialization has failed through middleware

Tags: asp.net-core

Let's assume this code:

```
public class Test
{
    public DateTime     Date        { get; set; }
    public string       Title       { get; set; }
}

[HttpPut, Route("test")]
public IActionResult test([FromBody]Test Data)
{
    ....
}
```

If the user is providing invalid json in the body, *Data* will be null.

Is there a way to catch this before the code is executed so I don't have to test for null on every API method?

I was thinking it may be doable as a middleware, but I have no experience with that, so I am not sure.

Comment: You should validate your model data. If properties are required, you should mark them as such and then the validation process (`ModelState.IsValid`) will tell you whether it’s correct or not.

Comment: but that means I need to add a "if (ModelState.IsValid) ..." to every call; I'm trying to find if I can catch that in the pipeline and return a generic error from a single place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use MVC filters to automatically perform validation when an action is excuted. To quote [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters#action-filters):

> You can use an action filter to automatically validate model state and return any errors if the state is invalid:
>
> ```
> using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
> using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;
>
> namespace FiltersSample.Filters
> {
>     public class ValidateModelAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
>     {
>         public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
>         {
>             if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
>             {
>                 context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(context.ModelState);
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> The `OnActionExecuted` method runs after the action method and can see and manipulate the results of the action through the `ActionExecutedContext.Result` property. `ActionExecutedContext.Canceled` will be set to true if the action execution was short-circuited by another filter. `ActionExecutedContext.Exception` will be set to a non-null value if the action or a subsequent action filter threw an exception. Setting `ActionExecutedContext.Exception` to null effectively 'handles' an exception, and `ActionExectedContext.Result` will then be executed as if it were returned from the action method normally.

Comment: Actually it doesn't really work like I expected: this forces me to decorate every call with an attribute; but since we have a framework that can be used in many ways, I'm looking for something that is totally automatic and where anyone writing a new rest call wouldn't even have to think about.

Comment: @Thomas You can also just decorate the controller to apply it to all its methods. Or you can [set the filter globally with the `AddMvc` call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters#filter-scopes-and-order-of-execution) to make it apply to all routes.

Comment: I didn't see that call before! perfect! thanks a lot again!